# How to check the phone number using Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, phone-number

I am trying to check the user input, I want the phone number to be like `000-0000`.

But my code here does not work as I want. I input

```
"123-4444444"
```

and it also matches.

I am not familiar with Regex, but I need to use it, so can you tell me how to change the pattern?

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d{3}-\d{4}");
if (!(regex.IsMatch(txtUpdatePhoneNumber.Text)))
{
   MessageBox.Show("Phone number format should be 000-0000", "Error");
}
```

Comment: to answer this we need more examples of your input. what do you expect after the fourth 4 to count it as a match? a space `\s`? end of string `$`? probably this: `@"\d{3}-\d{4}\b"` should do already the trick

Comment: Try this one: `^\d{3}-\d{4}$`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much, I changed it as you showed me, it works pefect.

Comment: Be careful when trying to validate international phone numbers. Neither international codes nor local numbers have a fixed size. What is a valid local number in one country can also be a valid international number for another country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks for me as you were writing a validator for user input. so (unfortunately I have to guess) in this respect you want only this number and nothing before or after.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
```

This would mean you need to ensure that the first 3 digits are really in the beginning of the string using `^` otherwise `IsMatch` would return `true` because it finds the pattern in `"something000-0000"`

and that after the last 4 digits the string is at its end using `$`  otherwise `IsMatch` would return `true` because it finds the pattern in  `"000-0000something"`

Answer (score 4):

You have to specify start and beginning

Please check the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/MZ4YPo/1

`^`: start of string
`$`: end of string

`^\d{3}-\d{4}$`

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{3}-\d{4}$");
if (!(regex.IsMatch(txtUpdatePhoneNumber.Text)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Phone number format should be 000-0000", "Error");
}
```